# Is the vector $\vec{PQ}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ more general than the vector $\vec{v}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering what would be the more general method in proving the proposition, "For every scalar quantity $c$, and for every vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $|c\cdot \vec{v}| = |c|\cdot|\vec{v}|$.

One could let $\vec{v} = \langle v_1,v_2\rangle$, but I think we can be more general by defining a vector $\vec{v} = \vec{PQ} = \langle x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1\rangle$ where $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2)$ are points.

So my question is whether or not $\vec{PQ}$ is more general than $\vec{v} = \langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ or is it that their generality is the same?